# I am writing a program for a sample test at hackerRank but my loop is not working or i must say i am receiving only one output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    n = list(range(1,n+1))
    for numbers in n:
        m3 = numbers / 3
        m5 = numbers / 5
        if type(m3) == int and type(m5) == int:
            return "FizzBuzz"
        elif type(m3) == int and type(m5) == float:
            return "Fizz"
        elif type(m3) == float and type(m5) == int:
            return "Buzz"
        else:
            return numbers
challenge = fizzBuzz(5)
print(challenge)
```

I think the function should iterate over n times but I am getting only one output. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you format your code first?

Comment: What is your expected output for input 5?

Comment: A `return` statement does just that -- it *returns* from the function. So of course, if you enter the loop, you only ever get one iteration.

Comment: because you are returning the function call after the first iteration of the for loop. you need to complete n iterations then return at the end.

Comment: It's because you are using return in every if statement, this means that any condition that is true will return the value and exits the function

Comment: If you want to return a list, then append to a list in each iteration, and return the list at the end.

Comment: Ok. so it means that we should not use loops and return together inside a function.

Comment: so for input of 5 i want to receive an output of : 1 , 2 ,fizz , 4 , buzz. All 5 outputs independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the output according to the `list(range(1, n+1))` then use `yield` instead of return.

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    n = list(range(1, n+1))
    for numbers in n:
        m3 = numbers / 3
        m5 = numbers / 5
        if numbers % 3 == 0 and numbers % 5 == 0:
            yield "FizzBuzz"
        elif numbers % 3 == 0:
            yield "Fizz"
        elif numbers % 5 == 0:
            yield "Buzz"
        else:
            yield numbers


challenge = list(fizzBuzz(5))
print(challenge)
```

Or you can initialize a `list` and append to the list then return

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    n = list(range(1, n + 1))
    ls = []
    for numbers in n:
        m3 = numbers / 3
        m5 = numbers / 5
        if numbers % 3 == 0 and numbers % 5 == 0:
            ls.append("FizzBuzz")
        elif numbers % 3 == 0:
            ls.append("Fizz")
        elif numbers % 5 == 0:
            ls.append("Buzz")
        else:
            ls.append(numbers)
    return ls


challenge = fizzBuzz(5)
print(challenge)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return statement to print statement or try this solution

```
def fizzBuzz(n):

    for num in range(1, n+1):

        if (num%3 == 0):
            print('Fizz')
        elif (num%5 == 0):
            print('Buzz')
        elif (num%3 == 0) and (num%5 == 0):
            print('FizzBuzz')
        else:
            print(num)

challenge = fizzBuzz(5)
print(challenge)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you divide any integer number by the '/' operator you always have the type float, even when division is an int. Test for yourself: `type(2/2)` returns float.
To check wheter N can be divided by M, it's usually better to test modulo `N%M==0`.

You can try this:

```
def fizz_buzz(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            print('FizzBuzz')
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            print('Fizz')
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            print('Buzz')
        else:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Yup it works Thanks. really appreciate it.